# Function preview in phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

Is there in phpstorm ability to preview function declaration in small window (like pressing ctrl+q shows documentation)?
Sometimes I want to see function/method code which is in the same file and afterwards I have to scroll and look place where I was before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**View | Quick Definition** <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + I</kbd> (or whatever shortcut you may have there).

[image]

Comment: Thank You! Even with screenshot :)